# make a multi thread websocket

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I made a Websocket server using ratchet and php it works fine but the problem is it's not multi thread and this makes the server replay late when multiple clients send messages to the server at the same time.
I want to know if there is any way to make it multi thread so each connection run on it's own thread or if it's not the right way give me a better one
Thanks!

Chat.php codes:

```
<?php
    namespace MyApp;
    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    require(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/inc/class/class-app_api.php');

    class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
        protected $clients;
        public function __construct() {
            $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
            echo 'server Started!';
        }

        public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
            // Store the new connection to send messages to later
            $this->clients->attach($conn);

            echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
        }

        public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
            $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
            echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n", $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');
                $obj = new \app_api($from, $msg);
                $res = $obj->handleRequest();

                if (is_array($res)) {
                    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
                        if ($from != $client) {
                            // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                            $client->send($res['data']);
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    $from->send($res);
                }
        }

        public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
            // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
            $this->clients->detach($conn);

            echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
        }

        public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
            echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
            $obj = new \venicehost_app_api($from);
            $conn->send($obj->setError('An error has occurred:' . $e->getMessage()));
            //$conn->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Server.php codes:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require_once("Chat.php");
    //require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        port,
        ip address
    );

    $server->run();
?>
```

Comment: do you mean thread?

Comment: @JacobNelson Yes!